# Java - OS X - Unicode mangled string

Tags: java, macos, unicode

I'm processing a Unicode text file using the Java platform on OS X. When I open the file using TextEdit or TextWrangler instead of seeing "Nattvardsgästerna" I see "Nattvardsg‰sterna" (which is incorrect). When I open the file using the Java io stream, I see the same incorrect `String` "Nattvardsg‰sterna".

When I open the file on my PC I see the correct String. I'm not sure where to start solving this problem... Is it an issue with my OS X set-up? Should I open the Java stream with a special flag?

Thanks.

P.S. I'm opening the file like so: `fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));`

P.S.S. Also, I should mention that I'd like to output the result as an SQL text file so it is important for the OS to distinguish **ä** correctly.

Comment: Looks like the encoding differs on your different systems.

Comment: What's the encoding of the file? How are you opening the file in Java?

Comment: It turns out that the textWrangler or textEdit can't guess the characterset of the file I'm trying to open.  However using TextWrangler I was albe to cycle through a few encoding and realized that Western (ISO Latin 1) seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `InputStream` reads bytes (not characters), so I assume when you say:

> When I open the file using java io stream

... that you really mean *"when I open the file using a Java `Reader`"*.

EDIT: Your comment says that you're doing this:

```
new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

An `InputStreamReader` has a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) that allows you to set the character encoding.  If you don't specify one, it will use the platform default.  It's unlikely the platform default will be unicode (on my Macbook, it's set to "US-ASCII").

In order to set the character encoding, you must create the intermediate input stream reader rather than that letting `FileReader` do it for you (because `FileReader` uses the platform default encoding).

Assuming the file is encoding using UTF-8, use:

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), 
                                         Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

Alternatively, you can change the platform default by supplying an argument to the JVM.  You can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/623036/1212960) for the full details, but the basic idea is that you set the `file.encoding` Java system property.  The linked answer provides a few ways to achieve this.

FURTHER EDIT:

> P.S.S. Also, I should mention that I'd like to output the result as an SQL text file so it is important for the OS to distinguish ä correctly.

The OS hasn't got anything to do with this.  The file system is just shuffling bytes around.  How those bytes are interpreted is entirely up to the *applications* that are reading those files.  This answer tells you how to make your Java program interpret the bytes correctly.  For your database to be able to interpret the bytes correctly, you'll need to configure the database encoding.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified this, but I'm using the following to open the file: new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))

Comment: @hba: I've made a slight edit so that you end up with a `BufferedReader`.  In short, you must create the `InputStreamReader` yourself so that you can specify the character encoding.

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow your suggestion, but ultimately, I'm worried that my solution won't work, because if mysqldev doesn't recognize the characterset then the sql strings generated by my app will be useless.

Comment: @hba: The OS hasn't got anything to do with this. The file system is just shuffling bytes around. How those bytes are interpreted is entirely up to the applications that are reading those files. This answer tells you how to make your Java program interpret the bytes correctly. For your database to be able to interpret the bytes correctly, you'll need to configure the database encoding.

Comment: Gerg, you're correct, I had to cycle through a few encodings to find the right one, now all my apps are working as expected (as well) - thanks.